# Cant access props and state within function in React class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props, react-lifecycle

I am trying to get values from my state and props in function. This function is fired under componentWillReceiveProps method. However when i try to console log my props and state values under that function i get 'undefined' as result. Is there something to do with my state not updating fast enough? Am i missing to pass props somewhere? Where could lay error and how could i get my function to handle correct values?

handleShow() function:

```
state = {
    training: {},
    isCreator: null
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
console.log(newProps);
    if (newProps.token) {
        axios.defaults.headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: newProps.token
        }
        const trainingID = this.props.match.params.trainingID;
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${trainingID}/`)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    training: res.data
                });
                console.log('treener', res.data.coach)
            })
            .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
        this.handleShow()
    } else{}

}

handleShow() {
    if(this.props.token == this.state.training.coach) {
        console.log('Props:', this.props.token);// value of undefined
        console.log('State.training', this.state.training.coach)// 
        this.setState({
            isCreator: true
        })
    }else{
        this.setState({
            isCreator: null
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know y props token not working maybe component not re-rendered check u receive props console. Log(this.props) and in componentWillReceiveProps the function handleshow u can pass newprops token in that way u can check condition with token and state handleshow (newprops.token). . Finally check parent component for props

Comment: Maybe you can try to use "componentDidUpdate" instead.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is unsafe (it won't work in React v17). Are you sure that the component receives some props?

Comment: yes, when i console log 'res.data' under axios.get, i get correct results. This means that my props are correct, but somehow i cant access them under my function.

Comment: @marzelin, it is strange because when i reaload page, props aare correct in function